# How to check if point is at the point of indentation in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a function to test whether the current point is at the point of indentation? i.e. the point being the possible result of `back-to-indentation`.

Comment: back-to-indentation moves the cursor to the first non-whitespace character. You want to know if the point is the first non-whitespace character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun point-at-indentation-p ()
  (if (= (save-excursion (back-to-indentation) (point)) (point))
      (message "I'm at indentation")
    (message "I'm elsewhere")))
```

Looks like a dead-simple one... not sure why do it other way.

Comment: I forgot about save-excursion! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following code will return `t` if point is at the first non-whitespace character of the current line, and `nil` otherwise:

```
(looking-back "^\\s-*")
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember such a function.  I'd use

```
(and (looking-at "[^ \t]\\|$")
     (save-excursion (skip-chars-backward " \t") (bolp)))
```

Note that using `looking-back` works, but `looking-back` is algorithmically inefficient so it can be dog-slow in some pathological cases.